# The Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool tries to install every boot

Tags: windows-7

It does not matter if I cancel or complete the installation, when I next start my PC the installer starts again.

The tool is not in my list of installed programs or in my start-up folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Task Manager and the program should show up in the Startup tab. Delete the entry to stop it from executing repeatedly. In case it doesn't show up there you can use the much more powerful [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to figure out where it's executing from.

If you want a better utility than the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool there are many, but I heartily recommend [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) or [WiNToBootic](http://www.wintobootic.com).

Comment: Thank you. Autoruns fixed it. Somehow the USB tool got tangled up with a Borderless Windowed gaming utility I downloaded but never used. Very weird.

Comment: Since you replaced the Win8 tag with Win7 later, for future readers' sake I'll just add that in Win7 to disable startup items they would use msconfig instead of Task Manager. Autoruns of course can be used as well.